# Solidity storage struct not compiling

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm new to solidity and I'm just experiencing with some simple code.
Basically I just want to create a struct that will store data permenantly inside a contract. According to the doc I need `storage` for that.
But the following code is not compiling except if I use `memory` instead. Why?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract test {

struct Selling {
    address addr;
    string name;
    uint price;
}

mapping(string => Selling) selling;

function sellName() constant returns (bool ok)
{
    address a = 0x4c3032756d5884D4cAeb2F1eba52cDb79235C2CA;
    Selling storage myStruct = Selling(a,"hey",12);
}
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
ERROR:
browser/test.sol:16:9: TypeError: Type struct test.Selling memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct test.Selling storage pointer.
        Selling storage myStruct = Selling(a,"hey",12);
        ^--------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first create the `myStruct` instance, it will be created in memory and then written out to storage (assuming you put the object into your `selling` map and don't declare your method `constant`) when the function returns. If you were to retrieve the item from your map in another function, then you would declare it as a storage variable.

See [this explanation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/initialising-structs-to-storage-variables) on Ethereum StackExchange for more details. The [Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#storage-memory-and-the-stack) also has a very good explanation of how variables are stored and when to use `memory` vs `storage`.

Comment: The solidity docs link is a 404.  RIP

Comment: @anthonygood Updated link to the most recent and closest version of the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar situation, the fix for this was:

```
function sellName() constant returns (bool ok)
{
    address a = 0x4c3032756d5884D4cAeb2F1eba52cDb79235C2CA;
    Selling memory myStruct = Selling(a,"hey",12);
    // insert 'myStruct' to the mapping:
    selling[a] = myStruct;
}
```